# How to host a site made with laravel 5 on a actual server?

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5, hosting

I have made a site using the Laravel 5 framework, but I have made the site on my local server(localhost). Now I want to host this site like other sites we host
on a server, but when I uploaded my files to the server, it didn't work, giving me an error.

I have already searched on Google but didn't find any perfect solution for this. I think some changes need to be done in the ***.env*** file or any other file.

Can anyone tell me what changes I have to make so that I can run the site perfectly like I do in the local server?
And one more thing: Do I have to install composer and laravel on my hosting server to run the files or not?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/u105583023/public_html/connection/public/index.php on line 50

Comment: connection is my folder name where i put my all files

Comment: Does line 50 look like this? Laravel 5.1 : `$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);`

Comment: yes exactly like this.

Comment: What PHP version are you running on the server? You can type in `php --version` in the console if I remember. As Laravel 5.1 needs PHP 5.5.9 or greater.

Comment: laravel version is 5.1.20

Comment: You need to upgrade your PHP to 5.5.9 or higher then. Class name resolution with `::class` was added in PHP 5.5 and the Laravel core code won't work on older versions

Comment: any other changes to be done?

Comment: well, if you don't want to update you could replace each `::class`. EG: `App/Http/Controller::class` - - > `'App/Http/Controller'`.. But considering how much files use this it will take hours.

Comment: can u give me the command to update php version? & where i will update inside the public_html or in the root directory?

Comment: I guess you're using a Linux server so typing ` sudo apt-get install php5` should do the trick. It doesn't matter where you execute this command as it will change the PHP running on your server, not for one folder.

Answer (score 4):

1.- Setup a project Laravel 5 in localhost correctly configured

2.- Double check the server configuration of PHP 5.4 (this because every little change on .htaccess file may change that config)

3.- Create a directory in the same level of public_html and put the project inside of that folder.

4.- Put the content of public (L5) directly on public_html (be aware of don't overwrite the .htaccess file accidentally)

Now... This is the "tricky part"... the structure

mail

perl5

php

public_html

[framework-folder]

ssl

Inside of `public_html` u can see all the files of public directory of Laravel 5

Go to index.php and edit the line 22

```
#From this
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
#To this
require __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and on line 36

```
#From this 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
#To this
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/pulcro/bootstrap/app.php';
```

The final step is to edit the `.htaccess` file and add some lines

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: worked for me. honestly, there are several ways to host a Laravel project on shared host. +1

Answer (score 0):

This might be the wrong version your PHP is running on the server as the requirements for Laravel 5.1 is PHP Version 5.5.9 or higher.

Comment: Not "might", it definitely is. `::class` is a PHP 5.5 thing called class name resolution http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php